# Update progress in center of screen

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How to set the update progress of ajax in the center of screen. Issue is coming when i have scroll down the page and it comes in the upper part of screen which is scrolled.

```
<div class="CenterPB" style="height:60px;width:60px;" >
                        <img alt="Loading..." src="abc.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0">
                        </div>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

.CenterPB{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -30px; /* make this half your image/element height */
margin-left: -30px; /* make this half your image/element width */
}
</style>
```

Comment: I was not able to replicate the problem you are talking about. 
this is what I did to try and replicate it. http://jsfiddle.net/3N53C/

I hope this will help you or someone find an answer.

Comment: [http://devarchive.net/update-progress-indicator.aspx](http://devarchive.net/update-progress-indicator.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from below link.
http://devarchive.net/update-progress-indicator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is in position property, as you are positioning box relatively to document coordinates instead of window.
Use:

```
position: fixed;
```

here is more about [position properties](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)